# Problems with division in c++

Tags: c++, division

I am using c++ on my project. However, when I try to make a simple division, it gives me a weird number.

for:

```
1.0 / 2.0 = -107374176.
1.0 / 3.0 = -107374176.
1 / 3 = -107374176.
```

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Show us the actual code, not just your interpretation of what is happening.

Comment: Indeed, it's not helpful at all without actual code.

Comment: I don't know why the down vote. I was doing cout << 1.0 / 2.0; I did the question as it should be!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`0xCCCCCCCC`, a typical value used for uninitialized memory, interpreted as a 32-bit float, equals `-107374176`.  You're printing an uninitialized float value.